# Temperature control function / algorithm

Tags: c#, c, algorithm

```
    double K1 = 50.0 / 300; // Warm up, 5 min, 20 - 70. Subject to change, if wrong
    double K2 = -50.0 / 120; // Cool down, 2 min, 20 - 70. Subject to change, if wrong

    double T = 20;
    const int ON_TIME = 7; // seconds. this should be calculated
    const int OFF_TIME = 2; // seconds. this should be calculated
    int onCounter = ON_TIME;
    int offCounter = 0;
    for (int t = 0; t < 1800; t++)
    {
        if (onCounter > 0)
        {
            onCounter--;
            T += K1;
        }
        else if(offCounter == 0)
        {
            onCounter = ON_TIME;
            // switch relay off here
        }

        if (offCounter > 0)
        {
            T += K2;
            offCounter--;
        }
        else if(onCounter == 0)
        {
            offCounter = OFF_TIME;
            // switch relay on here
        }
        Console.WriteLine("t: {0}, T: {1:F2}", t, T);
    }
```

What this function does is simulation of oven temperature during 30 minutes(Tt) linearly up to `70C`. Of course it doesn't work as expected. The input parameters are two linear slopes.

1. Oven temperature will increase from `20C` to `70C` during 5 minutes (Tw)
2. Oven will cool down from `70C` to `20C` during 2 minutes (Tc)
3. The step should be `1C` (Ts)

So the function will control relay, which will either turn on the oven or turn off. 
I have tried to just search those ON/OFF_TIME constans but it looks like I need more serious approach.

The question is - how to calculate `ON_TIME` and `OFF_TIME`.

Comment: You have your heating phase once 5 minutes long, once 7 minutes - is this just a typo?

Comment: No, it's not typo. `ON_TIME = 7` is not minute, it's actually seconds. `5` is the time in minutes, which requires for linear heating.

Comment: In reality these fuctions will be exponential, not linear.

Comment: @Olivier Jacot-Descombes : exactly! But at least I hope to solve it for linear input. Note that output should be as much linear as possible.

Comment: Would it not help to grab the system clock?

Comment: @C. Lang: This is just a model to demonstrate the problem here, eventually it will be driven by timers and work in embedded system :)

Comment: I guess I'm confused. Now your `ON/OFF_TIME` will be a function of the processing speed of the machine. It seems, although I could be wrong;), that all times are represented in seconds, but the outer loop which should occur over `1800` sec will not be the same length sec as the inner loops. That seems like it would make it much harder to simulate - don't know?

Comment: @C.Lang : please take this just as pseudo-code for algorithm development. In reality the body of loop will be called by 1 second timer tick. All times in the `code` are represented in seconds. I don't see the inner loop though. Those are just counters to keep track when to turn on/off relay within 1800 seconds to increase temperature linearly from 20 to 70. If by adjusting `ON/OFF_TIME` the output from the loop will give me numbers from `20.0` to `70.0` linearly I will be happy. Plz let me know if you are still confused and I will elaborate more, even update my question to make things clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about this one but I'm going to give it a shot for poops and giggles.

You declared `K1` as 50/300 representing the delta T over 300 seconds (5 min.) and you are restricted to a one degree step.

Isn't the question then, how many seconds must I wait to accomplish one degree?
Then isn't the answer...

```
 1/6(time) = 1 -> time = 1/(1/6) -> time = 6 seconds
```

And similarly for cooling

```
 5/12(time) = 1 -> time = 1/(5/12) -> time = 12/5 seconds -> time = 2.4 seconds
```

I realized the error in my earlier comment and think I understand your question better. If I'm still wrong let me know, I'll promptly delete.

#### Update

Your problem might be with something else. I was pretty confident that my math was correct so I wrote simple loops demonstrating the proof.

Here is the heating loop. I said that the time elapsed should be 6 seconds. This loop results with 70 degrees as it simulates 300 seconds per reqs.

```
        for (int fiveMinutes = 0; fiveMinutes < 300; fiveMinutes += 6)
        {
            T += (K1 * 6);
            Console.WriteLine("t: {0}, T: {1:F2}", fiveMinutes + 6, T);
        }
```

Results in:

```
t: 6, T: 21.00
t: 12, T: 22.00
t: 18, T: 23.00
/*
.....
*/
t: 300, T: 70.00
```

The cooling loop below results in 20 degrees.

```
        for (float twoMinutes = 120f; twoMinutes > 0; twoMinutes -= 2.4f)
        {
            T += (K2 * 2.4);
            Console.WriteLine("t: {0:F2}, T: {1:F2}", twoMinutes - 2.4f, T);
        }


t: 117.60, T: 69.00
t: 115.20, T: 68.00
/*
...
*/
t: 0, T: 20.00
```

In terms of your question of how to calculate the on/off time I feel it's accurate.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Something is wrong and with `ON_TIME = 6, OFF_TIME=2.4` I get `163C` when 30 minutes elapsed, instead of `70C`.

Answer (score 0):

Your constants ON_TIME and OFF_TIME must each represent 5 and 2 minutes respectively. You're expecting your T to change by 50C at rate 50C/300sec but in 7 seconds, which would result 1.17C change on the up cycle, down cycle will reduce T by 0.33C so every 7 seconds you'll end up with T+=0.83C

Your ON_TIME and OFF_TIME should be expressed in seconds or you can use them *60.

I don't know if you're trying to keep the oven warm in the middle of the loop, this algorithm will cause 4 heat/cool cycles and you end up with a relay in On position, you don't want to do that with real ovens :)

Consider this approach instead:

```
double dTemp = 50.0;
int cycleFor = 30*60;
int heatFor = 5*60;
int coolFor = 2*60;
double tBase = 20.0;
double temp = tbase;
for (int t = 0; t<cycleFor; t++){
   if (t<heatFor)
       temp = tBase + (t*dTemp/heatFor);
   else if (t>cycleFor - coolFor)
       temp = tBase + ((cycleFor-t)*dTemp/coolFor)
}
```

Comment: I don't agree with that. If ON/OFF_TIME will represent 5/2 minutes, then the temperature in oven will not change linearly during 30 minutes. I am trying to reach linearity from 20 to 70 degree during 30 minutes! 5/2 minutes is just information, which should help me to calculate on/off time.

Comment: @Pablo so what are the side-effects you're seeing if I'm wrong?

Comment: In your example the temperature goes as high as `645C` suddenly, then at the end of loop rest at `70C`. Disastrous :)

Comment: @Pablo how often do you think the relay switches on and off? The way I read your code that would be every 5 and 2 seconds respectively. Yet during each on/off cycle you change T by 50/300 on each step

Comment: no, in my code I switch on/off `7`/2 seconds, which I just select randomly because haven't found way to precisely calculate it. `K1` and `K2` may be wrong and can be adjusted to different values.

Comment: @Pablo read it again. If t<heatFor them t/heatFor < 1.0, so max temp will be tBase + t/heatFor * dTemp < 20.0 + 1*50.0, so 70C is max it will reach

Comment: I just put printing of `temp` variable at the end of loop. Now it goes from 20 to ~70 during 300 seconds then stays there and goes back to 20. Either I haven't explained enough or something else. 20 to 70 degree should happen during 1800 seconds linearly. And I should have a chance to control the relay.

Comment: I think my approach is fine, if it's possible to calculate ON/OFF times.

Comment: @Pablo in the code above you can turn relay on/off on boundary conditions (t=0, t=cycleFor-coolFor). Anyway, I'm sure you'll figure it out.

Comment: do you mean this will work correctly if the relays were connected even in program it shows different values? In other words your code will just calculate relay on/off times, but will not simulate temperature change?